# what is wrong with this oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM rnum,
               query.*
         FROM  (WITH myQuery AS(
                     SELECT column_b
                       FROM table_a a
                     WHERE a.column_a = 1234)
         SELECT b.column_e AS some_column
           FROM table_b b,
                table_c c,
                table_a a
      LEFT JOIN table_d d ON c.column_c = d.column_d
           JOIN myQuery mq ON a.column_b = mq.column_b
          WHERE b.column_b = a.column_b) query)
 WHERE rnum > 0
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or unexpected results?

Comment: error message, on the second join condition, saying ORA-00904, invalid string identifier

Comment: nope, I checked the column names, they are correct

Comment: which version of Oracle?

Comment: upgrade at least to 9.2.0.4 or try to use full join syntax (e.g. INNER JOIN instead of simple JOIN).

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix ANSI-88 and ANSI-92 JOIN syntax, pick one or the other.  Here's your query using ANSI-92 syntax:

```
WITH myQuery AS (
  SELECT column_b
    FROM table_a a
   WHERE a.column_a = 1234)
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT b.column_e AS some_column,
               ROWNUM 'rnum'
          FROM table_b b
          JOIN TABLE_A a ON a.column_b = b.column_b
          JOIN myQuery mq ON mq.column_b = a.column_b
          JOIN table_c c ON c.? = ?? --need join criteria here
     LEFT JOIN table_d d ON c.column_c = d.column_d) x
 WHERE x.rnum > 0
```

Your example lacks what TABLE_C joins on to - hence the `?` and `??`

I didn't know that `WITH` clauses can be defined in subqueries - I was sure I'd encountered an error in the past when attempting it in 10g.

Comment: -1 re your point #1 - the WITH clause CAN be defined within a subquery.
+1 re your point #2 - the mixing of the old and new join syntax is what is causing the ORA-00904 here.